# Symfony Doctrine: No se puede crear base de datos

Tags: mysql, symfony3, doctrine2

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial:

> https://symfony.es/noticias/2017/05/02/symfony-4-un-ejemplo-practico/

y me sale este error:

> Could not create database `symfony` for connection named default An
>   exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for
>   user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

El fichero .env lo tengo configurado así:

> DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:XXXXXX@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony?charset=utf8mb4&serverVersion=5.7"

Para acceder a mysql (lo tengo gracias a mamp), al root le he dado una contraseña; bien, mis preguntas son:

- 1) ¿Debería ponerla en la cadena de conexión arriba puesta donde
  pongo XXXXXX? ¿Debería ponerla entre comillas dobles?
- 2) ¿Puedo omitir la creación de la base de datos usando el comando:

  > ./bin/console doctrine:database:create

  y crearla yo usando el phpMysqlAdmin u otro gestor de BD? ¿Afectaría esta segunda forma de creación al correcto funcionamiento de la aplicación symfony?

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos,
Abelardo.

Comment: Tienes configurado tu app/config/parameters.yml con los datos de conexión a la base de datos? nombre de la BD, usuario, contraseña, puerto...

Comment: En el tutorial que sigo no se menciona que he de tener ese fichero, solo que es en ese fichero (.env).
Gracias por tu comentario. Lo veré más detenidamente. 
Saludos.

Comment: El ejemplo que estás leyendo supone que estás usando la versión 4 de symfony, que aun no está disponible en su versión final. No sé si en tu caso, estás usando esa versión o la última versión estable disponible, 3.x. En ese caso, este tutorial no te sirve.

Comment: Hola, @Muriano:

No, el tutorial sí es cierto que se titula algo así como "Crear una app como si tuvieras Symfony 4" pero, en realidad, es con la versión 3.3.8 (la 4 tiene previsto su publicación alrededor de noviembre, aprox.).

Saludos.

Comment: Primera noticia. Quizás sea un error en el nombre de la variable de entorno, el artículo habla de `DB_URL=mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony?charset=utf8mb4`, usando `DB_URL` en contraposición a la tuya, que es `DATABASE_URL`... Podrías probar a cambiarlo?

Comment: @Muriano:
Si lo cambio a DATABASE_URL me da este error: Yo creo que es un error de quien ha hecho el tutorial porque esta clase espera DB_URL y no DATABASE_URL.

In Container.php line 451:
                                                   
  Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_URL".  

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo config debes tener definidos tus EntityManagers los cuales tienen asociados las credenciales y drivers para la conexion.

Ejemplo Configuración doctrine:

`doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
        server_version: 5.7
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  utf8
        mapping_types:
            bit: boolean
            enum: string`

Debes elegir el **entorno** en el que estás trabajando que hará referencia a tu archivo config_prod, dev, local y por lo tanto a un entity manager con una configuracion u otra.
Si no añades al parametro `--env` acudire al que tengas por defecto, seguramente prod

El comando en symfony 3:
`./bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=local`

El comando en symfony 2:
`./app/console doctrine:database:create --env=local`

El parametro env, es por si tienes diferentes entornos: test, prod, local...

Comment: Hola, @Oskar:
Este es el mensaje de error que me da tras ejecutar la instrucción que pusiste:
The "--em" option does not exist. 

Por otro lado, ¿qué fichero es ese que pusiste como "ejemplo de configuración doctrine? ¿Dónde lo puedo encontrar?

Gracias y saludos cordiales.

Comment: El fichero de configuracion está en  `app/config`
Cierto, no debes especidicar el em

Comment: Déjame que le eche un vistazo a la entrada en symfony.es acerca del cambio de estructura que han llevado a cabo. Creo que por ahí debe estar la respuesta.

Gracias, @Oskar. :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a reemplazar

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:XXXXXX@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony?charset=utf8mb4&serverVersion=5.7"
```

Por esto:
Si el root tiene contraseña

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:contraseña@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony
```

Sin contraseña

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony
```

Y esto debería funcionar.

Con este comando

```
./bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

lo que haces es crear la base de datos configurada en el .env, que en tu caso se llamara symfony.